# Swift - How do I add a new object to an array inside another object that has a grouping field

Tags: arrays, swift, model

I have an array of events of type.

```
struct Event { var id: UUID, var title: String, var date: Date }
```

this array is inside another object with an occurrence title

```
struct Category { var occurs: String, var events: [Event] }
```

occurs defines if the event.date is before or after Now(), so that i can make Section Headers in a table to show Past and Upcoming sections.

I am only persisting Event(need id for Notification changes).

I am able to save and load data into an array of Category but how do I **add** a new event and get it into the correct "occurs" array.

Data Example (Event struc has init that assigns the UUID to id. )

```
    [
        Category(occurs: "passed", events: [
            Event(title: "Yesterday", date: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())!)
        ]),
        Category(occurs: "upcoming", events: [
            Event(title: "Tomorrow", date: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())!),
            Event(title: "Future", date: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 5, to: Date())!)
        ])
    ]
```

Category array is then consumed by a List/ForEach to spit out the Section and Body.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a way to figure out if the event has `passed` or is `upcoming`. You could add an extension to your `Event` struct to compute this:

```swift
extension Event {
    var occurs: String {
        let diff = date.timeIntervalSince1970 - Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        return diff >= 0 ? "upcoming" : "passed"
    }
}
```

Next you need to find the index of the category that matches the event's `occurs` value in your data array. You can do this by using the `firstIndex` method:

```swift
let newEvent = Event(
    title: "2 hours from now",
    date: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 2, to: Date())!)

let newEventOccurs = newEvent.occurs

if let index = data.firstIndex(where: { $0.occurs == newEventOccurs }) {
    data[index].events.append(newEvent)
}
```

Notice we use an `if-let` binding because it's possible you don't have a category in your array for the event. In this case, you will want to add the category to your array with the new event.

Comment: and "data" would be the array of Category objects, correct? Damn, I need to go back and review my array "lack of" knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, data would be set to your data example you gave.